# Cycling through a hex colour spectrum

Tags: colors, hex, arduino

I'm working on some code with Arduino, and I'm trying to get a strip of LEDs to cycle through the spectrum of colours in order. I have done this in the past by changing the red green and blue values independently, but the current LEDs I am working with take Hex values (for example, 0xFF0000). How I can do this?